# how to interact with spotify's window app -change track etc

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, spotify

I'm doing a new hobby project after work which involves making my own custom C# music player, which plays  and interacts from various locations such as youtube, spotify and Windows Media Player

I've done some googling on this and found a heap on spotify's web player but not for spotify's own windows application.

I've done majority of my UI but hit a brick wall with interacting with other apps. I would love some advice on how to interact (change track etc) with spotify etc, as i have never done an application which interacts with another app, as i do mostly MVC stuff.

Thanks, i appreciate any feedback

(PS sorry if this has been asked, but clearly google doesnt want to show me it ha)

Answer (score 2):

You can interact with it by sending messages to the Spotify window (at least on Windows). AFAIK this only lets you send commands though, not receive any information in return.

You can send a message with ID 0x0319, wparam of 0, and lparam of a specific action to the Spotify window: `SendMessage(spotify_hWnd, 0x0319, 0, cmd_id)`

The IDs for actions are listed below.

> ```
>     CMD_NONE        = 0
>     CMD_PLAYPAUSE   = 917504
>     CMD_MUTE        = 524288
>     CMD_VOLUMEDOWN  = 589824
>     CMD_VOLUMEUP    = 655360
>     CMD_STOP        = 851968
>     CMD_PREVIOUS    = 786432
>     CMD_NEXT        = 720896
> ```

The only example I know of that does this is pytify (https://code.google.com/p/pytify/), which I have used successfully somewhat recently. It may have required some tweaking (some of the above values may not be 100% correct) - I will look into what I did when I'm back on that computer.

Comment: May I ask where did you get the *ID 0x0319* ?

Comment: @IneedHelp See the MS developer docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-appcommand

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I still don't see where you got the specific 0x0319 ID, it's nowhere on that page.

Comment: @IneedHelp Sure it is, right at the top of the page:

#define WM_APPCOMMAND                   0x0319

Comment: duh, I feel so stupid. Thank you very much for the info!