# Sending Keyboard inputs to Spotify whilst not in focus

Tags: c#, autohotkey, spotify, sendkeys

I have an AHK script (below) which sends various commands to the Spotify desktop app globally while in the background to perform various actions, however I play an MMO which has an always running anti-cheat which shuts the game down when it detects AHK because people can use it for macros, etc.

```
; "CTRL + Alt + UP"  Increase the volume.
^!Up::
DetectHiddenWindows, On
WinGet, winInfo, List, ahk_exe Spotify.exe
Loop, %winInfo%
{
    thisID := winInfo%A_Index%
    ControlFocus , , ahk_id %thisID%
    ControlSend, , ^{up}, ahk_id %thisID%
}
return
```

The anti-cheat does not detect/care about C# programs/applications so I'm porting over the code to C# and have found a way to send commands to the Spotify application to perform a majority of the stuff I wanted via *SendMessage*:

```
private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101; //Tried using these to no avail
private const int WM_KEYSYS = 0x0104;
private const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;

var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Spotify").FirstOrDefault(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.MainWindowTitle));
IntPtr hwnd = proc.MainWindowHandle;
SendMessage(hwnd, 0x0319, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)917504);
```

This command would play/pause the current song as that is what the final number (917504) corresponds to. Spotify also provides command codes for volume up/down, however they affect the entire volume of my PC, not just spotify which is obviously not what I want.

I've tried literally hundreds of combinations of *PostMessage* and *SendMessage* and I simply cannot figure out how to send the keys 'Ctrl' + 'Up' to make the volume increase (and vice versa for decrease). **while in the background**. I don't want the window to be brought to the foreground, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I also mentioned the AHK script because from my digging I *think* the ControlSend function is ran from this point in the source code https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/blob/90b5c2ac3208c38b9488a72fc3e6e4f9cf20b276/source/keyboard_mouse.cpp#L135 , however I don't understand C/C++ enough to be able to figure out how to override the functions that require the window focus, etc.

Comment: Your C# code will send the same commands as AHK. So if AHK is blocked your app will be block as well. If it's not, then your game block the process name `ahk_exe` from running so just rename the exe file

Comment: The game doesn't seem to care what the program running the ahk script is called as it blocks it regardless of its name/what process it's running under

Comment: So it's blocking the c++ sendkey that AHK is sending. C# sends the same exact same sendkey api. How the same behavior can yield different result ? The only way is that there is a second factor based on AHK itself

Comment: The issue isn't the anticheat preventing specific functions like SendKey being run, it's that it'll block AHK regardless of if it's renamed, moved or under a different process name. It'll also block AHK scripts if they're compiled to .exe's. I'm more focused on getting the C# code to work than worrying about the anticheat.

Comment: @Franck some games are so stupidly made that they e.g simply wont launch if you have any AHK script installed. Whoever thought of that, has some real issues. I had one game (CoD BO4) that crashed instantly upon launch with no error message if any AHK script was running. After days of trying to figure it out with Google/the game's support, I gave up. Then like a year later I saw a post about it online. Absolutely absurd the developers would do this. But anyway, more on topic, OP try if the game wont detect AHK v2, or AHK_H. I think encrypted AHK_H could have a real chance.

Comment: Oops, typo, _if you have any AHK script **running**_, not installed. That doesn't make sense of course. And here's a forum link to AHK_H https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewforum.php?f=65

Comment: Have not tried it personally, but [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31733319/2330053) you can send a CMD_VOLUMEUP command directly to the main spotify window.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I mentioned the volume down command in the post and how it changes the entire system sound rather than spotify itself

Comment: I missed that somehow. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe think about compiling your AHK script to an exe: It might not be blocked this way. And you would have no effort to transfer your AHK solution.